# why $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_{i} = 1$ defines a hyperplane?

Tags: convex-optimization

I am doing exercise 2.15 of "[convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)". While the [solution](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) confused me a lot.

as indicated by the solution:
$\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i =1$  defines a hyperplane.

while it's different from the dinition of hyperplane in page 27, 2.2.1 of the book:

A *hyperplane* is a set of the form $ \{x | a^T x=b\}, $ where $a \in \mathbb{R}^n, a \neq 0$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}$.

by the definition, solution of x could be considered as a line orthogonal to y axis in the x-y 2-dimensional coordinate, and also could be considered as a hyperplane in the other spaces.

how $\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i =1$  defines a hyperplane ? it's quite weird!

Comment: For future reference: `$\mathbb{R}$`, or equivalently, `$\Bbb{R}$` both produce "$\mathbb R$" which is what you probably meant when you say $b\in R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consistently with the notation in use, $\{p\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \sum_{j=1}^n p_j=1\}$ is the hyperplane $\{p\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \mathbf 1^\top p=1\}$, where $\mathbf 1$ is the vector such that $\mathbf 1_j=1$ for all $j$.

Comment: so, the hyperplane determined by this constraint is n dimensional ?  each solution of p could be considered as one dimension.

Comment: @YangGaoguang Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, the dimension of the affine subspace $H_{A,b}=\{x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, Ax=b\}$ is, when the set is non-empty, $\dim \ker A=n-\operatorname{rk}A$. In this case, the dimension is $n-1$.

Comment: thank you for your help, thank you very much.